# Real standard input in Racket

Tags: input, racket

It seems that Racket is incapable of reading a string from STDIN.

```
$ racket
Welcome to Racket v6.4.
-> (define (s) (read-line))
```

OK, `s` is an alias for a call to `read-line`.

```
-> (printf "You entered: ~a\n" s) 
You entered:
```

Failure: The string is printed, but Racket does not wait for keypress / STDIN / EOF / EOL.

```
-> (define n (read))
a
-> n
'a
```

Failure: This makes a call to `read` and waits for EOF / EOL, then assigns to `n`, but `n` is assigned the *symbol* `'a` ***not*** the *string literal* `a`.

```
-> (read-line)
""
```

Failure: calling `read-line` doesn't wait for STDIN, just returns the empty string.

```
-> (read-string 5)
asdasdasdasd
"\nasda"
; sdasdasd: undefined;
;  cannot reference undefined identifier
; [,bt for context]
```

Failure: only reads 5 bytes of STDIN, and apparently `eval`s the rest of it... ?

```
-> (read-string 500000)
asdasd
asdasdaas
a
asdasd
asdasd


asdasd
```

Failure: doesn't return until exactly 500000 bytes have been read, and doesn't return on EOL.
Somewhat like Python's `input()` which returns a string when `EOL` is found, or [Factor](http://factorcode.org)'s `readln` which does the same, how can I read raw data from the `current-input-port`?

Comment: your initial code works fine to read a line. (define s (string-trim (read-line))

Comment: @JosephPoirier as mentioned in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36430713/4532996), in 2016 there was a problem with interactive read-line and that's what i was using

Comment: ah, I didn't realize you needed a wait state. It works when data is there. I think returning empty data would be manageable with an if statement using sleep, a timer or other mechanism.. like a listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a limitation of the Racket's REPL's input handling. If you write a standalone program it will work fine.

Here's a quote from the mailing list that explains the problem:

> A known limitation. The REPL implemented by plain `racket' does not
>   separate the input stream for REPL expressions from the program's
>   input stream.

More details: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/racket-users/0TTsA9-3HDs/9_mMWsgKFOMJ

Comment: Good to know, thank you, although it's kinda annoying. Is there a workaround, or will it be fixed?

Comment: `(define (my-read-line)
  (let ([contents (read-line)])
    (if (string=? contents "")
      (read-line)
      contents)))` is what I suppose I'll use now.